# Load a range of cells in to a single form text box

Tags: vba, excel

I am using MSO Excel 2013 and I am trying to load a range of cells in to a single text box in a form. It is a help file I'm writing. As long as I load just 1 cell, it works fine. When I try to load a range of cells, I get an error. Is there a way to make this work? My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub cmbTopic_Change()
Me.lblTopic.Caption = Me.cmbTopic.Value

Select Case Me.lblTopic.Caption
    Case Is = "Understanding The Software"
        Me.txtHelp.Text = Worksheets("HelpFile").Range("A2").Text
    Case Is = "First Time Use"
        Me.txtHelp.Text = Worksheets("HelpFile").Range("B2").Text
    Case Is = "General Instructions"
        'this is where I'm getting an error
        Me.txtHelp.Text = Worksheets("HelpFile").Range("C2:C4").Text

End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: What error do you get, at what line? So you have a text box in a form, and you're trying to put in multiple values there?

Comment: Try removing ".Text" after your ranges. Im not sure ".Text" is a property of Range. I know "Value" is, but by default it will give you the value.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to construct a String of cell values and then write it to the textbox.

You may try something like this...

```
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Sheet2.Range("C2:C4")
    If Str = "" Then
        Str = Cell.Value
    Else
        Str = Str & vbCrLf & Cell.Value
    End If
Next Cell
Me.txtHelp.MultiLine = True
Me.txtHelp.Value = Str
```

Comment: That totally worked sktneer! Thanks a bunch! Ya'll make this coding seem so easy lol. Thanks for the help everyone!